# Why is it called an “Indian file”?

Tags: american-english, phrase-origin, north-american-english, canadian-english

I recently came across a US phrase, *Indian file*.  This is utterly unheard of in the UK, and probably outside North America; at least I’ve certainly never heard of it.  The phrase would be expressed in British English as *single file*.  Why is it called *Indian file* in the US?  I’m guessing the phrase has something to do with the prevalence of Amerindians, but I can’t see any obvious etymology.

Comment: OOC, where in the USA was the person who said this from?

Comment: Actually it was a guy from Quebec saying it in French where I first saw it.  :-)  I was then informed by someone who's on the east coast of the US that it was a known expression in US English.

Comment: @Jez, This is the literal translation of "En file indienne" /ɑ̃ fil ɛ̃.djɛn/.  Another synonym in French is "à la queue leu-leu" /a la kø lø lø/ because wolves also walk in this way one behind the other.  Since Canadian English has been influenced by Canadien French, I'd be inclined to believe this comes from French.

Comment: It is known in Britain too (though rare these days) - for example it is mentioned in [Brewer](http://www.bartleby.com/81/8839.html).

Comment: I'm an East Coast native (from English-speaking Canada, now residing in the U.S.), and this is the first I've heard the term.  I have always heard and used *single file*.

Comment: Use of any "ethnicity" in descriptive terms has vanished in recent decades, because of the possible worry of them being socially inappropriate.  Because "indian giver" was perpetuating stereotypes, I believe other "indian-this" and "indian-that" have vanished from common usage.

Comment: Were there any negative Indian- combinations other than *Indian giver*? The ones I know about, *Indian summer*, *Indian corn,* and *Indian file,* don't seem to relate to any negative stereotypes (unlike *Chinese fire drill,* for example).

Comment: @PeterShor There are also various plants and animals who se common names start wtih *Indian*, like **Indian pipe** (*Monotropa uniflora*) and **Indian paintbrush** (numerus species in genus *Castilleja*, which has a cool name).  **Indian rice** (*Zizania aquatica*) seems to have become *wild  rice*, although it isn’t. I don’t see any stigma associated with **Indian blankets**, either.

Comment: @AlainPannetierΦ Might you know of a good online French etymological dictionary?  Monolingual only, please.

Comment: @Jez The OED’s first citation for *Indian file* is from 1758, which by simple temporal arithmetic by definition makes it British.

Comment: @PeterShor This one probably isn’t too nice: “1965 *Wildlife Rev.* (Victoria, B.C.) Mar. 19 ― Cougars, also known as panthers, pumas, catamounts, mountain lions, and **Indian devils,** are large unspotted cats.” I’ve never heard that particular *Puma* synonym myself. Perhaps it’s not used that way any longer. And this one is even worse: “1937 H. H. Langton in P. Campbell *Trav. Interior Parts N. Amer.* 71 ― The Wolverine··has long been extinct in the province [sc. Nova Scotia], where it is remembered as the **‘Injun devil’**.”

Comment: @tchrist, sure: [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/). It's a little bit like the OED with the year of the citations. I also use the Littré, a CD/iso, which is also available online. However only the CD has the etymology I believe. Finally, my pet French etymological dictionary is the [dictionnaire historique de la langue française](http://www.lerobert-historique.com/) by eminent lexicologist Alain Rey (I only have a paper copy however).

Comment: I (British English speaker) knew it in childhood - I have not heard it so much recently.

Comment: FWIW, “fila indiana” is quite common in Italian, where it means the same thing.

Comment: @tchrist your comment serves as a valid answer to a related question I just made, so I wrote a [CW answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/499973/280768) linking to your comment, just in case you wanted to add something.

Comment: @AlainPannetierΦ I think it's [marcher ou avancer] à la file indienne or en file indienne, in the CNRTL. file is feminine....[question: how can there be a French etymological dictionary other than a monolingual one?] https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/file

Comment: In the very first Sherlock Holmes book "A Study in Scarlet" - 

"Between the two ran the irregular track, so narrow in places that they had to travel in Indian file, and so rough that only practised riders could have traversed it at all." A British writer (A.C. Doyle) in 1887, but writing about America.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Presumably because this is the way the settlers thought American Indians walked on trails through the forest. They probably did; if you have narrow trails, this is the only comfortable way to walk them. By the way, in my experience, it's not "an Indian file"; unlike "single file", "Indian file" is not used as a noun.

> They walked Indian file.
>   *or* ... arranged Indian file.

but not

> *They formed an Indian file.

Comment: That's true.  Indian file is an adverb, not a noun.  I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @Jez, it's not related to hunting: the idea was that the crafty, naturally warrior-gifted natives walk "indian-file" because in that way **nobody knows how many warriors there are in the group**.  Furthermore, you're supposed to go in the **footsteps of the next person**.  This idea, "single-file" is a completely normal technique used today by military people, "special forces" and the like from time to time...single-file or Indian-file.

Comment: Regarding why it's so common in Britain, children's books etc .. of course, the kids do it in **Peter Pan** (even in the Disney movie) when they are sneaking around - a big cultural reference.

Comment: The OED has: ***“Indian file***, the same as single file, so called because the North American Indians usually march in this order.”  Reading further, it seems that *Indian* as a prefix is, or at least was once used, to mean *North American* in a more general sense than one specially referencing its autochthonous peoples alone.

Comment: @Peter: Could you include a link to [***Indian giver** "one who gives a gift and then asks for it back" (1848). Also compare **Indian summer**. **Indian elephant** is from c. 1600; **Indian corn** is from 1620s; **to walk Indian file is from 1758***](https://www.etymonline.com/word/indian) or similar? (Per [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/280768/charlie) under a potential duplicate, I find I'm diffident about just unilaterally making the edit myself! :)

Answer (score 17):

Indians in single file:

[image: Indian File]

Canadians in single file:

[image: Canadian Indian File]

Answer (score 3):

Just as a point of information, I've lived all my life in the USA, most of it in Oklahoma where (American) Indian peoples are more than 10% of the population and culturally very prominent. To my knowledge I have never before heard that term.

If I had to hazard a guess, this probably relates to the way some particular tribe used to wage war. A lot of tribes looked at warfare as a very stylized affair, much like Europeans did in the Middle Ages. You'd typically get more glory by running up and slapping one of the enemy than by actually killing them (as this was actually more difficult). However, Indians were/are not one people with one coherent culture, so these things can vary quite a bit.

So the term is probably a regionalism.

Comment: If it is a regionalism, it could be due to the "Indian" people having to move through more or less densely wooded terrain: Single file means that only the man in front has to blaze the trail. Oklahoma being relatively sparsely vegetated in general (from my limited experience), you might not be expected to have heard this. How does that sound?

Comment: @JeffSahol: the first record of this appears to be [in Massachusetts](http://www.answers.com/topic/indian-file), which was definitely wooded terrain.

Comment: TED, it is not to do with "stylised" -- it's an ingenious military technique!  "Camoflage" for a group march.  If a large brigade march side by side, or in rabble, it's easy for someone who comes later to guess it was a large group.  But if a large group correctly walks single-file style (stepping in each other's treads, etc), it is much harder to know what is going on. This cliché is seen in a 100 western movies, I'm surprised not so many know this!  John Wayne's sidekick -- Look Sarge, there's only one of 'em!  John Wayne -- there could be a hundred Comanches walking Indian-file, Easterner!

Comment: @JeffSahol - A large amount of the tribes in Oklahoma were forcibly transplanted there from the SE US. That actually is a fairly forested area. They were mostly settled in the eastern part of the state of Oklahoma, which is actually decently forested too, like neighboring Arkansas. There are of course native plains tribes in Oklahoma too, mostly in the western part of the state, but that's not where I live. :-)

Comment: @Joe Blow - Ah! Good reference there. Perhaps I just haven't watched enough old John Wayne movies. :-)

Comment: How odd that a native AmE speaker does not know this. Perhaps you are young?? See this for a 1791 reference in a dictionary. https://books.google.com/books?id=mZASAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA476&dq=%22indian+file%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNoOSzvr7iAhWxT98KHcxSD_oQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22indian%20file%22&f=false

Comment: @Lambie - In my 50's now. I suppose for some people that would be considered young. I certainly wasn't around in 1791.

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps the fact of being exposed to mountains of BrE at an early age plus having parents from MA and TN respectively has anything to do with it. I'm scratching my head here. :) Can't figure out why I know it. All I know about your lovely state is the song.

Answer (score 1):

I've lived in Ireland all my life, and am familiar with this term. I wouldn't have thought of it as an Americanism, though I did know it refers to/derives from "American Indians", not Indian Indians. I don't know what the geographic spread of the phrase is, but I'm nearly certain it's popped up in British children's books.

Comment: And yet I have lived in Canada and the U.S. all my life, and have never heard this term before!

Comment: As I've commented above, it's mentioned in [Brewer](http://www.bartleby.com/81/8839.html), so it's certainly not restricted to the US.

Comment: I certainly heard it growing up, and I lived in the U.S. all my life, as well. I expect political correctness has made it less common lately (although *Indian file*, unlike *Indian giver*, is not pejorative).

Comment: @JohnY Would you mind telling us what region of the US? See my comment under T.E.D. above. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was born and raised in the UK and have long known this term, though most likely through my fairly wide lifelong reading. As already noted, the term has the same meaning as "single file". In fact, it is also syntactically equivalent: both are used adverbially. E.g.

To walk (in) single file.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one has mentioned this so far:  In the U.S. a common saying is

> single file, Indian style

which might be used, say, as an indication to other members of a group walking together to use a single file.  A native of the western U.S., I've never before heard the term *Indian file*, though.

Comment: I'm a native of California, and although I've never heard anyone *say* "Indian file", I've often seen it in (old) books.  But this is the first time I've ever heard of 'single file, Indian style.'  Where is it common?

Comment: @MT_Head: Well, my wife and I grew up in different counties in northern California, and we were both familiar with 'single file, Indian style' in our childhoods.  A little research shows it is sometimes used as a 'call' in square dancing.

Answer (score 0):

Just read this in Age of Anxiety (WH Auden, 1947):

"Along the esker
Following a fox with our fingers crossed
Or after an ogre in Indian file,
We stole with our sticks through a still world of
Hilarious light . . ."

Auden puts these words in the mouth of an English woman living in New York, who is recounting a childhood memory.  And of course Auden himself was English-born.  That would suggest to me that the term was known in UK English usage.

Comment: Auden lived in the U.S. from 1939 on, so you can't conclude that it's known in the UK from Auden.

Answer (score -1):

Because that is how the Red Indians hunted — one after the other — following the trail of the animals.

Answer (score -1):

Boston Public Schools (i.e., Boston, Massachusetts, USA), 1950s, commonly used by teachers to instruct children to single-file (used here as a verb).

Comment: Can you cite any source?

Comment: This doesn't explain why it is called *Indian*, which is the focus of the question.